# How do I prevent node text to move away or not overlap on my tree in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, text, d3.js, tree, overlap

I have created a tree using D3, and am having problems with some text strings being too long. The tree moves it's nodes accordingly to the tree structure, but how do I take the node-text into consideration?

[image]

If "T-ALL" on this picture had a longer name, it would overlap with the node to its right. If long enough it would make the two texts unreadable.

Here is my source code for drawing the tree:

```
function drawTree(source) {

        vis.selectAll(".graphTitle")
            .transition().duration(800)
            .attr("x", w/2-100)
            .attr("y", -100)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "16")
            .style("font-family", "'Hoefler Text', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .transition().duration(700)
            .attr("x", w/2-100)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .text(getCurrentGene());

  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 60; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); drawTree(d); });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d, i) {return d.size;} )//14.5)
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return nodeColor(d.size); });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .text(function(d) { 
        if(d.name == "root"){
            return "";
        } else {
            return d.name;
        }
       })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  link.style("stroke", function(d, i){
    if((i == (((link.size()/2)-1)) || i == (((link.size()/2)-2))) && (AMLsIncluded == true)){
        if(AMLsIncluded){
            return "white";
        }else{
            return "#ccc";
        }
    } else {
        return "#ccc"
    }
    return "#ccc"
  });
  //console.log("all: " + ((link.size()/2)-2) + " - " + ((link.size()/2)-1));

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  AMLsIncluded = false;

    //CSS
$(".node circle").css({"cursor":"pointer", "fill":"#fff", "stroke-opacity":".51", "stroke":"steelblue", "stroke-width":"1.5px"});
$("path.link").css({"fill":"none", "stroke-width":"1.5px"});
$(".node text").css({"font-size":"11px"});
}
```

Any help is appretiated

Comment: The short answer is that the tree layout doesn't take things like this into account. One option would be to move the labels depending on how long they are and there the other nodes are, e.g. in the case you mention you could put the label below the node.

Comment: Yes, I had a hunch that text wasn't taken into account, and I thought about putting the below the node, and this is a good suggestion, but if the two nodes are next to each other (my example) and the text strings are long they will still overlap. Also, the only way I know of checking the length is by checking the amount of chars used, is there a way to get a length in pixels or something similar? Because two string like "aaa" and "WWW" will have different visual length, even thought they both have 3 chars.

Comment: The only way to get the exact dimensions when drawn is to actually draw the text, measure it, and remove (or adjust) it.

Answer (score 0):

change this line,

normally i would put 13

```
  nodeEnter.append("svg:text") .attr("x", function(d) { 
       return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
   })
```